# Replace spaces with dashes and make all letters lower-case

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I need to reformat a string using jQuery or vanilla JavaScript

Let’s say we have `"Sonic Free Games"`.

I want to convert it to `"sonic-free-games"`.

So whitespaces should be replaced by dashes and all letters converted to small letters.

Any help on this please?

Answer (score 783, accepted):

Just use the String [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Replace) and [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/toLowerCase) methods, for example:

```
var str = "Sonic Free Games";
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
console.log(str); // "sonic-free-games"
```

Notice the `g` flag on the `RegExp`, it will make the replacement *globally* within the string, if it's not used, only the first occurrence will be replaced, and also, that `RegExp` will match one or more white-space characters.

Comment: A variation I came up with uses \W which represents any nonalphanumeric character. This is useful for something like 'A&P Grocery' which would become 'a-p-grocery'. `str.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase();`

Comment: Mind not quoting the regexp part, ie `replace(/\s+/g, ..` and **not** `replace('/\s+/f', ..` (without apostrophes)

Comment: What if I want to remove the spaces at the start and end of the string?

Comment: @RomelIndemne Nowadays you can use the [`String.prototype.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) method: `str.trim().replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()`

Comment: Thanks, nice one. Now I need the other way around xD JK

Answer (score 48):

Above answer can be considered to be confusing a little. 
String methods are not **modifying** original object. They **return** new object. 
It must be:

```
var str = "Sonic Free Games";
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase(); //new object assigned to var str
```

Comment: I think it is important to note that the accepted answer was edited to incorporate this concept

Answer (score 45):

You can also use `split` and `join`:

```
"Sonic Free Games".split(" ").join("-").toLowerCase(); //sonic-free-games
```

Comment: Be aware of side-cases, for instance where some space are at the beginning, they won't be replaced

Comment: That's not true, take this for example  ```" Sonic Free Games".split("  ").join("-").toLowerCase(); ```

Comment: does not work for other whitespaces than space

Answer (score 16):

A very straightforward approach is to use the JavaScript String replaceAll() method.

```
"Sonic Free Games".replaceAll(' ', '-').toLowerCase(); //sonic-free-games
```

For simple replacements like this, a regex is often overkill.

This is simpler and more readable.

However, if you still need a regex, you can use them with this method as well. See the [moz docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) for an example.

If you need IE support, you'll need a polyfill.

Comment: Please explain why this is better than the accepted answer and consider adding a comment instead.

Comment: A simple test shows `"Sonic Free Games".replace(' ', '-').toLowerCase(); //
"sonic-free games"` that's why the other answers are using regex with `g`

Comment: @FemiOni the answer says "replaceAll" not "replace"

Answer (score 7):

If you have lodash in your project, you can try kebabCase

```
_.kebabCase('Sonic Free Games')
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#kebabCase

Answer (score 5):

```js
var str = "Tatwerat Development Team";
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, '-');
console.log(str);
console.log(str.toLowerCase())
```

Answer (score 2):

@CMS's answer is just fine, but I want to note that you can use this package: https://github.com/sindresorhus/slugify, which does it for you and covers many edge cases (i.e., German umlauts, Vietnamese, Arabic, Russian, Romanian, Turkish, etc.).