# jQuery reverse SEF urls?

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I'm using this code to create SEF url strings:

[Replace space with dash and make all letters lower case using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983648/replace-space-with-dash-and-make-all-letters-lower-case-using-javascript)

I was wondering if there was a way of reversing this using jQuery? Example:

this-is-a-test

into

This Is A Test

Comment: shouldn't the end result be "This Is A Test"?

Comment: Yep that's correct lol I don't know why I did the -'s lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

split the string on hyphens, capitalize first letter, lowercase the rest...then join them back up on a blank space:

```
var string = 'this-is-a-test';
var words = string.split('-');
var list = [];

for ( var i=0, l=words.length; i<l; i++ ) {
  var word = words[i];
  list.push(word.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + word.substr(1, word.length).toLowerCase());
}

console.log(list.join(" "));
```