# mirror (and alter) input field jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace space with dash and make all letters lower case using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983648/replace-space-with-dash-and-make-all-letters-lower-case-using-javascript)

I've got this code that mirrors an input field to another

```
$('#name').bind('keypress blur', function() {
    $('#slug').val($(this).val());
});
```

perfect! But let's say I need to mirror it and alter a little. if `#name`'s value is `My New Value`, I want `#slug`'s value to be `my-new-value`.

So I guess what function(s) would I through in there to make the text lower case and replace spaces with hypens? Also, is this the best way to go about doing that?

Comment: you can do this with string functions or a regex replace. This is sort of a broad question. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Possible duplicate [Replace space with dash and make all letters lower case using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983648/replace-space-with-dash-and-make-all-letters-lower-case-using-javascript)

```
$('#name').on('keypress blur', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    val = val.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
    $('#slug').val(val);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate awareness. It is very similar, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`.toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```
$(this).val().toLowerCase().replace(/[ ]/g, "-")
```

Comment: You sir, are brilliant! Works like a charm! :) A little bit more of a concise answer, which is exactly what I was looking for :)