# Strip spaces and make string lowercase with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script that duplicates the content I'm entering in one field into another.

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/wk3nmc76/

I was wondering if it's possible I could change the 2nd field to strip spaces & make the value lowercase?

```
<p><input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name" placeholder="Full Name"/></p>
<p><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name"></p>
```

```js
$('#full_name').keyup(function(){
   $('#last_name').val(this.value);
});
```

Comment: `$('#last_name').val(this.value.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, ''));` https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/d2uyw659/

Comment: Phenomenal, @Satpal - many thanks :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To achieve this you can use a combination of `toLowerCase()` and a regular expression to remove all the spaces. Try this:

```js
$('#full_name').on('input', e => {
  $('#last_name').val(e.target.value.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name" placeholder="Full Name" />
</p>

<p>
  <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
</p>
```

---

***2023 Update***

The `replaceAll()` method now has broad enough browser support for it to be a viable alternative to using a Regular Expression:

```js
$('#full_name').on('input', e => {
  $('#last_name').val(e.target.value.toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ', ''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <input type="text" name="full_name" id="full_name" placeholder="Full Name" />
</p>

<p>
  <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
</p>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983648/replace-space-with-dash-and-make-all-letters-lower-case-using-javascript is a pretty good duplicate.

Comment: Many thanks, Rory - this worked brilliantly. Really handy to know this for future work.

Comment: Sorry, If I am asking too late, can we use replaceAll(" ", "") method instead of Regex here ? Kindly suggest @Rory McCrossan

Comment: @Saikumar yes, it now has good enough support: https://caniuse.com/?search=replaceall. When the question was originally answered this was not the case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got the context now. @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#full_name').keyup(function(){
   $val = $(this).val()
   stripped_val = $val.replace(' ', '');
   lowercase_stripped_val = stripped_val.toLowerCase();
   $('#last_name').val(lowercase_stripped_val);
});
```

Or, in short:

```
$('#full_name').keyup(function(){
       $val = $(this).val()
       modified_val = $val.replace(' ', '').toLowerCase();
       $('#last_name').val(modified_val);
});
```