# Create Human-readable URLs with React Router Parameters and Firebase RTD

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-router, react-router-dom

Basically I am trying to find out the best possible way to structure my URLs on my website in terms of SEO. Right now I have my news URL's structured like this:

http://example.com/news/

http://example.com/news/-FirebaseKey

Where I can - from the last example; fetch the article information directly from the firebase key that is provided in the URL as a parameter. However, I know this is not optimal for SEO - and I was wondering how I could change this to having my URL structure something like this:

http://example.com/news/this-is-an-example

How exactly would I approach this?

I can't really think of any other ideal solutions, when it comes to the use of primary and foreign keys, because I can't really uniquely identify a 'title' from my firebase database.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you would like to load content on a route based on the URL parameter, but instead of having a unique key, you want a human-readable string.

To do this you would set a custom firebase key name instead of a unique autogenerated key when you create it.

Define a custom key:

```
firebase.database().ref('collection/' + customKey).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl
  });
```

Don't Push an autogenerated one:

```
firebase.database().ref('collection/').push({
        username: name,
        email: email,
        profile_picture : imageUrl
      });
```

I'm a little confused because you also say that you `can't really uniquely identify a 'title'`. A route must be unique. The same URL cannot take you to two different websites. Provided the `this-is-an-example` bit in the example above is unique then my approach above will work.

Comment: Great idea, I will try this now. However, how would I approach the replacement of 'spaces' in the title, and replace it with '-' in order to create a 'binding URL'?

Comment: You misunderstand. The custom key is not your title value, it is the bit that you would like to see in your url. There would never be spaces, it would be `.ref('collection/' + 'this-is-an-example')`. The wording might match your title, but your key is separate. For example, if you were to update your title, this key string would stay the same.

Comment: If you are asking how you replace spaces in a string with dashes then search SO or open a new question. That is a separate issue. I'd either use  regex or split and join, examples of both here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983648/replace-space-with-dash-and-make-all-letters-lower-case-using-javascript